# Weekday preceded or not with "di"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Is there any difference between "sabato" and "di sabato"? Example:

- Tornerà sabato.
- Tornerà di sabato.

Do both imply that I'm talking about the next Saturday?

Comment: La prima frase può essere usata per dire «sabato prossimo»; la seconda per dire che il soggetto tornerà un certo, specifico, giorno della settimana.

Comment: Thanks, @Benedetta! So "tornerà sabato" = "he/she will come back on Saturday" and "tornerà di sabato" = "he/she will come back on a Saturday"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I giorni  della settimana sono proceduti dall'articolo determinativo o dalla preposizione ***di*** se ci riferiamo a qualcosa che succede ogni settimana in quel giorno.
>
> Per esempio:
>
> La domenica (= ogni domenica) mangio sempre molto, però di lunedì (= ogni lunedì) vado in palestra.
>
> Se invece ci riferiamo a qualcosa che è successa un giorno particolare e basta, non useremo né l’articolo né la preposizione.
>
> Per esempio:
>
> Martedì sono andata dal medico, mentre venerdì ho cenato al ristorante.

[learnamo.com](https://learnamo.com/tempo-italiano-preposizioni-articoli/)

So:

*"tornerà di sabato"*  means that they will come back on Saturday, we don’t know which one, but it will be a Saturday. So as suggested above (every Saturday) in the sense that any Saturday will potentially be the day they will come back.

Comment: This meaning of "di"+weekday does not make sense in the example that I have given in my question ("Tornerà di sábato"). Couldn't it mean an indeterminate Saturday (this week, next week, next month, etc) in that example?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - tornerà ‘di sabato”  means that they will come back on Saturday, we don’t know which one, but it will be a Saturday. So as suggested above (every Saturday) in the sense that every Saturday will potentially be the day they will come back.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. I'd appreciate if you could edit your answer to include that. The meaning of "di"+weekday currently provided in it does not cover my example.

Comment: I think the correct English is "*any* Saturday", not "every Saturday".

Comment: @DenisNardin - it is actually every (Sunday) in the example in Italian, my point is that it can suggest any ( Sunday ) as OP is looking for.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I meant that I think the last sentence of your comment should be "any Saturday will potentially be the day they will come back". In any case, it's not a big deal, I'm just a bit pedantic :)

Comment: Where does the second quotation come from?